# Is it possible to create graphs taking data from json in Zabbix?

Tags: json, monitoring, zabbix

Would it be possible, in any way, to create json code that zabbix can understand and recreate on a graph?

**Eg:**

I have this json:

```
{
    "response:" {
        "success": true,
        "server": {
            "name": "Test Server",
            "alive": true,
            "users": 25
        }

    }
}
```

And I would like to have a simple graph where I can see the value of **users**.

I might be asking a nonsense here but I was reading about the [URL element](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/config/visualisation/screens/elements#url) and it looks like it is possible but couldn't find any type template or any info on how to send the data.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Zabbix trapper item and send such values with the [zabbix_sender](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/concepts/sender). The values will be processed as any normal item values by Zabbix, and graphs will be available as well.